# Xamarin App Crashes on Xml load from string [android]

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xml-parsing

if i debug my Android App it will always crashes if i load a xml from a string in an XmlDocument. The loading into the string works fine.

Error:

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <to>edit</to>
</note>".
```

My Code:

```
private void Xmlload()
    {  

        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("note.xml")))
        {
            xmlString = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        textView1.Text = xmlString;
        Xml();
    }



   private void Xml()
    {        
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlString);          
    }
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Use LoadXml insead of Load : doc.LaodXml(xmlString).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Load` method loads XML from a path.  You want to use `LoadXml`, which loads a string containing XML

```
XmlDocument.Load(string path);

XmlDocument.LoadXml(string xml);
```